# Can a question be moved from one account to another?

Tags: support, questions, user-accounts

A friend of mine was looking for a word in an Im conversation. I asked the question for him on English.SE as if it were my own question. being the smart ass he is he decided to create an account there himself, and now I feel badly for stealing his question :-)

Is it possible for moderators to reassign a question from one account to another so he can get the credit he deserves?

Comment: Diamonds can't. But we'll have to see if a Dev is able to. If you don't have any other contributions, though, you could probably get your account merged into your friend's, and then just create a new account.

Comment: It's not *that* important @Grace :-)

Comment: @Grace he's actually coming along quite nicely by accident on that site, so I don't think he wants to void his existing account there ;)

Comment: Amusing - this is now two questions I've generated for you. Isn't guilt awesome? Seriously, I don't care about rep, I just wanted to know the word.

Comment: Feature request: enable Reverse Morris Trusts on SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since is this reassigning a single question's ownership, moderators cannot do this. They can merge accounts, but that would leave only one account.

The only way that this could be done is by a developer. If they do not see this question, you can email them at team@stackexchange.com, but there is no guarantee that they will be willing to do this for you.

However, even if they are unwilling to do this, remember that it's only one question. You get the reputation for taking the prerogative to ask the question, and I'm sure your friend appreciates getting the answers even if he's not getting the rep. And since you've introduced him to the site, I have no doubt that he'll ask his own questions and build up his own rep anyway, so it's not too terrible if the devs decline to do it.

Comment: He just commented above that he doesn't care about rep, so it's not worth email `team@`. I think my criticism/concern over the new editing features have already made them upset enough with me, no need to make it worse ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that [this can be done](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/4257/tryaria). You just have to know the right people. And a big **thank you** to her! :-)